# Logstash "mutate - Failed to convert "false" into boolean."

Tags: json, elasticsearch, boolean, logstash, kibana

I am currently pulling json in my Logstash (7.8.1) configuration from an API then filtering it then outputing it to Elasticsearch. For starters a simple curl call to my API outputs the following json that I am trying to sanitize in the filter portion of the logstash configuration file:

```
{
"numRowsToRead": "5000",
  "cosmosDocCount": "\"5000\"",
  "totalFragmentCount": 5000,
  "lastSuccessfulBatchTimestamp": "\"null\"",
  "streamingDriven": "\"false\"",
  "totalRows": "5000",
  "lastBatchId": "\"null\"",
  "status": "TASK_FINISHED",
  "samplingRatio": 1.0,
  "mergeStrategy": "timestampOrdered_pdg",
  "lastSampledTimestamp": "2020-07-31 19:45:03.0"
}
```

The issue I am having here is on the `streamingDriven` attribute as I would like it to be of type *boolean* not *string* so for that I updated my filter configurations with the following:

```
mutate{
    gsub => ["streamingDriven","\"",""]
    convert      => {
                    "streamingDriven" => "boolean"
                    "totalRows" => "integer"
                    "numRowsToRead" => "integer"
                    "cosmosDocCount" => "integer"
                    }
    remove_field => ["@version", "http_poller_metadata"]
}
```

For some unknown reason `streamingDriven` remains a *string* and I see the logs output:

```
[WARN ] 2020-08-10 19:59:52.612 [[main]>worker1] mutate - Failed to convert "false" into boolean.
{
                 "streamingDriven" => "false",
                  "cosmosDocCount" => 0,
                   "numRowsToRead" => 5000,
    "lastSuccessfulBatchTimestamp" => "\"null\"",
                     "lastBatchId" => "\"null\"",
                   "mergeStrategy" => "timestampOrdered_pdg",
              "totalFragmentCount" => 5000,
                          "status" => "TASK_FINISHED",
                       "totalRows" => 5000,
                   "samplingRatio" => 1.0,
            "lastSampledTimestamp" => "2020-07-31 19:45:03.0",
                      "@timestamp" => 2020-08-01T02:45:03.000Z
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) seems to indicate that `"streamingDriven" => "boolean"` should convert "false" to false of type boolean and I am trying to figure out why it is not working for me. Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do to get this working. The trick was to use a second mutate like so:

```
mutate{
        add_field => {
            streaming_driven => "%{streamingDriven}"
        }
        gsub => ["streamingDriven","\"",""]
}
mutate{
    convert => {
        "streaming_driven" => "boolean"
    }
    remove_field => ["@version", "http_poller_metadata"]
}
```

Now I am getting a boolean value.